# Theoretical ground which forbids the use of Frequentist SAR specifications in Bayesian estimations?

Tags: bayesian, jags, frequentist

**Abridged question version**

Given the constraints I face when mixing frequentist SAR specifications (e.g. regressand autoregressive process, involving binary correlation structure) with Bayesian estimation methods, it looks like I shouldn't. Is there a theoretical ground which forbids me to do so ?

---

**Original question version**

Am I using JAGS-4.2.0 in a too non-conventional way ? *i.e*, trying to fit a SAR(p) model as it is usually specified by frequentist statisticians.

I apply this non-conventional use to Anselin (1988)'s [crime data](http://www.dm.unibo.it/~simoncin/columbus.html) in what follows.

Because JAGS is not designed to fit simultaneous variable relationships, many problems occur. An illustration of this with a JAGS SAR(5) model specification:

```
00 model{
01        # LAGGING ENDOGENOUS VARIABLE ##############################
02        W[1:49,1:49] <- lD*D[,] + lD2*D2[,] + lD3*D3[,] + lD4*D4[,] + lD5*D5[,]
03        W_CRIME[1:49] <- W[,] %*% CRIME2[]
04        
05        # LIKELIHOOD ###############################################
06        for (i in 1:49){
07                CRIME[i] ~ dnorm(CRIME_mean[i],tau)
08                CRIME_mean[i] <- W_CRIME[i] + cCts*cts[i] + cInc*INC[i] + cHoval*HOVAL[i]
09        }
10        # PRIORS ###################################################
11        lD ~ dunif(-100,100)      # VERY NONRESTRICTIVE PRIORS
12        lD2 ~ dunif(-100,100)     # EXPECTING TO OBTAIN
13        lD3 ~ dunif(-100,100)     # SUBVERSIVE POSTERIORS
14        lD4 ~ dunif(-100,100)     # FROM WHICH e.g. NORMAL DISTRIBUTION
15        lD5 ~ dunif(-100,100)     # MAY EMERGE.
16        cCts ~ dunif(-100,100)
17        cInc ~ dunif(-100,100)
18        cHoval ~ dunif(-100,100)
19
20        tau ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
21        sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
22 }
```

To the line `03`, the variable name `CRIME2`, which is a copy of `CRIME`, is a way to workaround the following JAGS error:

```
Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Unable to resolve the following parameters:
CRIME[1:49] (line 3)
Either supply values for these nodes with the data
or define them on the left hand side of a relation.
```

I tried to specify my likelihood in cleaner ways, *i.e.*, by substituting the `CRIME_mean[i]` definition on line `08` for

```
CRIME_mean[] <- Si[,] %*% (cCts*cts[] + cInc*INC[] + cHoval*HOVAL[])
```

where matrix `Si` is defined as follows:

```
# IDENTITY AND SPATIAL FILTER MATRICES #####################
for (i in 1:49){
        for (j in 1:49){
                I[i,j] <- ifelse(i==j, 1, 0)
        }
}
S[1:49,1:49] <- I[,] - W[,]
Si[1:49,1:49] <- inverse(S[,])
```

However, because the inverse function only works on symmetric positive-definite matrices (since JAGS-2.1.0), it results in the following error:

```
Error : RUNTIME ERROR:
Cannot invert matrix: not positive definite
```

and restricting the prior bounds of my autoregressive coefficients so as to get S positive definite would have computational implications that are not managed in JAGS (eigenvalues, etc...), also, although row-stochastic because boolean, my `D`-like matrices are not remarkable at all ( *e.g.* not Toeplitz ones, etc...).

**Given the constraints I faced, it looks like I may not mix frequentist SAR specifications with Bayesian estimation methods. What is the theoretical ground which forbids me to do so ?**

But still, when I estimate my SAR(5) via Bayesian estimation (with JAGS) on the one hand and via frequentist classical ML estimation on the other hand (with a checked-against-pysal homemade extension of pysal), the results are :

[image: ML vs BAYESIAN-JAGS]

---

*Following Whuber's comment*

#### Why do I provide these results

**First**, given that I am asking whether I am out of control, these table/graphics are provided in order to facilitate your job if you want to tell me why.

**Second the table** which compares $\textrm{SAR}(5)$ ML and Bayesian estimates, and shows that the former is comprised in the latter. Which is a signal indicating that it seems to be okay to use JAGS in this way.

**Third the graphics**, to show that, despite all difficulties that are faced if one uses JAGS like this, obtained results do not exhibit (canonical) pathologies. I.e. :

*...From top to bottom and from left to right...*

1-*Density plots* of each parameter show that each chain has converged in a similar space.

2-*Autocorrelation plots* show that the quality of chains are rather good since they converge (even if it more or less takes time).

3-*Running mean plots* show that each parameter's chain is rather quickly approaching its target distribution.

4-*Traceplots* look random, showing that sampling process time series do not state chain problems and allows for assessing convergence.

All these elements give the feeling that it is theoretically allowed to use JAGS in this way. But in this case, I do not understand why this use is so rare, while this is the most direct and easy way to handle spatial model (not having to play with likelihoods to integrate and so on...). On google, typing "JAGS spatial lag model" returns stuffs about CAR models, involving correlation structure with continuous interaction of the type distance decay, *e.g.* what if one wants to model binary interactions ? Am I dead wrong ?

Comment: Given the heavy use of code and output, consider emphasizing the general (non software specific) nature of your question.  The purpose of the graphics is unclear, because they are offered without any commentary or interpretation.  Are they really needed?

Comment: I cannot bring myself to read through all your stuff that comes without any explanation of what is going on, but in general, anything you can fit in a frequentist manner can be done in a Bayesian way. It is just a matter of a sensible prior specification (it is possible that a poorly chosen prior causes a lot of problems or distorts the results in weird ways) and sometimes of an effective parameterization (this is surprisingly often of critical importance). Personally, I feel Bayesian approaches can solve some difficult problems in a very nice way.